# How to fake Realm Results for tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, realm

I have written a test to validate if a function is called :

```
  func test_getTaskLists_doNotCreateOrUpdateTaskListToStorageWhenSynchedLocally() {

   ...    
    let (datasource, restAPI, fakeTaskListStorage) = ...

    datasource.getTaskLists() { (taskLists, error) -> Void in
      ...
      XCTAssertEqual(1, fakeTaskListStorage.readAllInvocationCount)
      ...      
    }
...
  }
```

The function is mocked to bypass super implementation and the issue is that the function returns a Results which I can't figure out to build/mock in order to return a valid object so the compiler stops complaining...I know I could just call super.readAll() but here I actually want to convert my test data (fakeTaskLists) to a fake Result object so everyone is happy...not sure if thats possible

```
class FakeTaskListsStorageRealm : TaskListStorageRealm {
    var fakeTaskLists:[TaskList]?
    override func readAll() -> RealmSwift.Results<TaskList> {
      readAllInvocationCount += 1
      //Here I want to return fakeTaskLists somehow...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to instantiate `Results` directly. Subclassing `Results` doesn't allow too. I think the best way is hiding `Results` by protocol like `ResultsWrapper` rather than using `Results` directly.

But an easy workaround is using in-memory Realm when testing.
The `FakeTaskListsStorageRealm`'s `readAll()` can be written using in-memory Realm as follows:

```
class FakeTaskListsStorageRealm : TaskListStorageRealm {
    var fakeTaskLists:[TaskList]?
    override func readAll() -> RealmSwift.Results<TaskList> {
        readAllInvocationCount += 1
        return try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "test")).objects(TaskList.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar wrapper and can confirm this approach is working – I have implementation of wrapper with array so I don't use in-memory Realm.